# Curl login and store cookie and save that

Tags: php, curl

This is the Login.php file.
I want to Login using curl 
this the login.php code

```
    <form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="sign_in" />

<h2>LOGIN  WITH</h2>
<div class="agile_ihj">
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="w3l_o">
<div class="strip">OR</div>
<div class="grid_3 grid_5 w3-agileits">

            </div>
</div>
<h2>Welcome</h2>

<div class="agileinfo">
  <input type="number" name="c_phone" placeholder="Phone No" required="">

</div>


<div class="agile_par">

</div>
<div class="w3l_but">
<button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
</div>
</form>
```

how can i login and store cookie and save that .. because i have to scraping the data form website.

Comment: The code snippet you've posted is pure html, there's no PHP there.

Comment: yea ... sorry ... can i loging  or not ?